# C malloc memory corruption when inserting into Hashmap

Tags: c, hashmap, malloc, nodes

I have created my own hashmap implementation but am getting a `malloc(): memory corruption` error when attempting to insert a record.

From main.c

```
...
// works fine
err = init_hash(num_inds, config->num_ncs);
...
// this is the call that causes the crash
hash_rc = insert(dob_id, age);
```

from hashmap.c

```
/*------ Declare Global variables --------*/

unsigned long HASH_SIZE;
int NUM_NC;

/*------ Hashmap Node ------*/
struct node{
    unsigned long long id, least_highest_crossovers, *hap_address;
    int target, hap_address_set;
    long age;
    unsigned long long *rels_ids;
    unsigned long long *rels_hap_address;
    unsigned long long *rels_crossovers;
    struct node *next_node;
};

struct node **hash_map = NULL;

/*------ Declare Required Functions ------*/
int init_hash(unsigned long num_inds, int num_ncs){
    NUM_NC = num_ncs;
    
    // average of 5 nodes per index
    unsigned long n = ceil(num_inds/5);
    HASH_SIZE = n;
    
    // allocate memory for the hash table
    hash_map = malloc(HASH_SIZE * sizeof(struct node*));
    if(!hash_map){
        return 1;
    }
    for(unsigned long l=0; l <=HASH_SIZE; l++){
        hash_map[l]=NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Get a hash code from an id
unsigned long long hash(unsigned long long id){
    return ((id * 31) % HASH_SIZE);
}

// Insert a record into the hashmap
int insert(unsigned long long id, long age){
    printf("hash_map size: %lu\n", HASH_SIZE);
    printf("num ncs: %d\n", NUM_NC);
    unsigned long long hash_ind; 
    hash_ind = hash(id);
    // new node
    printf("Before node malloc\nid: %llu\nage: %ld\nhash_ind: %llu\n", id, age, hash_ind);
    struct node *new_n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));    // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS!!
    printf("After node malloc\n");
    new_n->id=id;
    new_n->age=age;
    new_n->target=1;
    new_n->hap_address_set=0;
    new_n->least_highest_crossovers=0;
    new_n->rels_ids = malloc(NUM_NC * sizeof(unsigned long long));
    new_n->rels_hap_address = malloc(NUM_NC * sizeof(unsigned long long));
    new_n->rels_crossovers = malloc(NUM_NC * sizeof(unsigned long long));
    new_n->next_node=NULL;

    if(hash_map[hash_ind] == NULL){
        hash_map[hash_ind] = new_n;
    }else{
        ...
    free(new_n);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
[user@server ~]$ ./hash
hash_map size: 5
num ncs: 30
Before node malloc
id: 19109
age: 1140
hash_ind: 4
*** Error in `./pedMap': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000014d3340 ***
```

I have read a number of questions on SO regarding malloc errors but the majority seem to occur where an index out of bounds is attempting to be updated. This is not the case here as I am just trying to malloc for a new pointer node??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating `HASH_SIZE` elements here:

```c
    hash_map = malloc(HASH_SIZE * sizeof(struct node*));
```

but later on in the code you are initializing `HASH_SIZE + 1` elements with `NULL` (notice the `<=` in the loop instead of the `<`!):

```c
    for(unsigned long l=0; l <=HASH_SIZE; l++){
        hash_map[l]=NULL;
    }
```

Subsequent `malloc` calls will then detect that you overwrote memory that was used by `malloc` itself.

I'd recommend using the address sanitizer (ASAN) while developing software (when using GCC and/or Clang just pass `-fsanitize=address` to the compile and link flags), as that would find these errors at the points where they are happening, and not at a later point when the error already occurred.

Comment: Btw. irrespective of the off-by-one error: the line `unsigned long n = ceil(num_inds/5);` will not do what you expect, because `num_inds/5` is still an integer division, hence automatically defaulting to round-to-zero. To actually use the floating point ceil function you'd have to do a floating point division (e.g. `5.0` instead of `5`), or, much better, just use the standard trick to perform `ceil` for positive integers: `unsigned long n = (num_inds + 5 - 1)/5;`